# Declare nested object leaf key values as undefined in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Consider a nested object like below

```ts
class Person {
    name: string = 'name';
    address: {street: string, pincode: string} = {street: 'street', pincode: '44555'};
}
```

There is a utility function(**undefinedAllLeadNodes**) which undefines all leaf nodes. So passing a new Person() creates below

```ts
person.name = undefined
person.address.street = undefined;
person.address.pincode = undefined;
```

If i declare as below

```ts
export function undefineAllLeafProperties<
    T extends object
>(obj : T) :  {[key: string] : any} {
    ...undefine all leaf nodes here
}
```

It shows compilation error for person.address.street and it sounds fine for `{[key: string] : any}` return type declaration.

But What can be the proper return type for the utility function(undefinedAllLeadNodes)
so that i can access it like below without any errors

```ts
person.address.street = 'update only street';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may define such a type like this:

```ts
type Undefine<T extends object> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? Undefine<T[K]> : T[K] | undefined
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wj5A6W)

Here we're using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to iterate over all keys (using [keyof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) operator) of the provided `T` object and [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check whether the value of `T[K]` (using [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types)) is an object again. And when it is we recursivly iterate over the `T[K]` keys. Otherwise  (when `T[K]` is not an object) we just change it's type to allow `undefined` value along the main type of `T[K]`.

Keep in mind that inside the `undefineAllLeafProperties` function code you may have to type assert return values . Because typescript generally [cannot infer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) the exact shape of the [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) when it depends on unspecified generic type parameter.