Define TypeScript type so that a config matches configs in Record<string, Component<Config>>?
I have a component that allows users to define a set of fields in a Record<string, Component<Config>> format and pass in a config which will then render a component dependent on the config passed. I noticed that the config param should only ever be of the type passed into Component<Config> and looked to create a type structure such that each record in the fields param will define the available types inside the config param.
Defined Types:
interface FieldConfig<TType extends string, TOptions = object> {
  type: TType
  options?: TOptions
}

export interface FieldComponentProps<
  TValue,
  TFieldConfig extends FieldConfig<string>,
> {
  config: TFieldConfig
  value: TValue
  onChange: (value: TValue) => void
}

export type FieldComponent<TValue, TFieldConfig extends FieldConfig<string>> = (
  props: FieldComponentProps<TValue, TFieldConfig>,
) => ReactNode

What I'm looking for:
Say we have 2 field components:
export type SwitchFieldConfig = FieldConfig<'switch'>
export type SwitchFieldConfig = FieldConfig<'switch'>

export const StringField: FieldComponent<string, StringFieldConfig> = ({
  value,
  onChange,
}) => (
  // TODO: Use Devify input
  <input value={value} onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)} />
)

export const SwitchField: FieldComponent<boolean, SwitchFieldConfig> = ({
  value,
  onChange,
}) => <SwitchInput value={value} onChange={onChange} />


If we were to pass these components into the fields param, the expected type of config should be SwitchFieldConfig | SwitchFieldConfig, like so:
<SectionField
  config={config} // StringFieldConfig | SwitchFieldConfig
  fields={{string: StringField, switch: SwitchField}}
/>

What i've tried:
interface SectionFieldComponentProps<
  TFields extends Record<string, TFieldConfig>,
  TFieldConfig extends FieldConfig<keyof TFields & string>,
> {
  config: TFieldConfig
  fields: Record<keyof TFields, FieldComponent<any, TFieldConfig>>
}

This is the best solution I have gotten but the problem is i've somehow created a type that can only have a single record in the fields param such that if I do:
<SectionField
  config={{ type: 'switch', label: '', path: '', options: {} }}
  fields={{ switch: SwitchField, string: StringField }}
/>

I get the type error The types of 'config.type' are incompatible between these types. Type '"switch"' is not assignable to type '"string"'., unless I remove the string: StringField.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68250350/define-nested-object-with-optional-parameters-leaf-key-values-as-undefined-in
